# Extract URL String from Email Getting Rid of All Other Text

Tags: string, csv, email, outlook, trim

I have a vba script that extracts the text of an email.  I am able to select the specific email no problem and debug print that to a file.  I can't figure out how to extract or trim down in the same script the exact line that I need:

```
Public Function GetEmailString()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItem As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim s As String
Dim n As Integer

n = FreeFile()

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test")
Set olItem = olFolder.Items

olItem.Sort “Subject”

i = 1

For Each olMail In olItem
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "UPS Report Available") > 0 Then
    Open "D:\test.txt" For Output As #n
        s = olMail.body
        Debug.Print s ' write to immediate
        Print #n, s ' write to file
        Close #n
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next olMail
End Function

The contents of the email are this:

At the request of whoever of Test Company, this notification provides access to reports regarding shipper shipment information. The reports are available for download by accessing the link provided below.

Do not reply to this e-mail. Shipper Company and Whoever of Test Company will not receive your reply.

Message from Whoever of Test Company:
Daily Quantum View Report for 1V0650

Reports Available for Download:
https://www.ups.com/email-qvm/downloadCVRpt?id=Ym)Wm4K1t4EyTVWj3Bcm3BZNlhj2Io(86B3YZ0rzJQ6dxEL4O6S(BTNtF08IcdWvoPiJ9JGgw7(SrxzFI6(4yItUToowZLPI)rkb2o7HRxtHUFPz6GMiNnjsI6G)j(iKEWkTDKnH7YnwNeBEDUAPw__&loc=en_US

This e-mail was automatically generated by Shipper Company e-mail services at the request of Whoever of Test Company. Shipping Company and Whoever of Test Company will not receive any reply to this email. Please contact Whoever of Test Company directly if you have questions regarding the referenced shipment or wish to discontinue this notification service.
```

I am able to print that to a text file the contents that I need it trimmed down to are this:

```
https://www.ups.com/email-qvm/downloadCVRpt?id=Ym)Wm4K1t4EyTVWj3Bcm3BZNlhj2Io(86B3YZ0rzJQ6dxEL4O6S(BTNtF08IcdWvoPiJ9JGgw7(SrxzFI6(4yItUToowZLPI)rkb2o7HRxtHUFPz6GMiNnjsI6G)j(iKEWkTDKnH7YnwNeBEDUAPw__&loc=en_US
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I am ultimatly trying to get that one string in a text file so I can later read it and use the xttp to download the csv file that this link generates automatically into an access database table.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simple method to return what I need.  I am then going to write this to another file and scoop that up to be read by a database:

```
Public Function ReadFiles()
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fsoFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim fsoFile As File
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim key As String ' Part before ":"

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPandF As String
Dim strLine As String

strPath = "D:\"
strFile = "Test.txt"
strPandF = "D:\Test.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'New FileSystemObject
Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(strPath)
Set fsoFile = fso.GetFile(strPandF)
Set FileText = fsoFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
TextLine = FileText.ReadLine 'read line
key = "https://www.ups.com/email-qvm"
If Left(TextLine, 29) = key Then

MsgBox TextLine
End If
Loop

FileText.Close

End Function
```